# Какое оборудование нужно чтобы писать софт под iPhone?

Tags: c#, objective-c

Есть Windows ПК, есть iPhone.

Какое еще минимально затратное оборудование нужно чтобы писать софт под iPhone?

Как таковой язык программирования (objective-C, C# и т.д.) или среда разработки (например Xamarin) роли не играет.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Официально iOS SDK (набор средств для разработки) доступен только под Mac OS X, а она, в свою очередь, официально доступна только на Mac'ах. Для сборки любых приложений, к сожалению, он потребуется, в том числе для сборки приложений на базе Xamarin, Unity - все эти фреймворки только создают проекты для XCode, которые уже нужно собирать под Mac OS X.

Самый дешёвый Mac Mini в России сейчас стоит 40990 (к нему нужен ещё монитор).
В качестве другой альтернативы можно взглянуть на сервисы аренды Mac'ов вроде [MacInCloud](http://www.macincloud.com/pricing/compare) (сам не пользовался, правда). Вам выдаётся удалённый доступ к Mac'у, на котором вы уже можете собирать приложение.

Comment: а что мешает собирать с "Хакинтоша" ? Кроме морально-этических причин.

Comment: @pavel, скорее всего то, что хакинтош не проходит проверку железа в AppStore. Соответственно xCode - не поставить. По крайней мере слышал на последней MAC оси так.

Comment: И Хакинтош не на всё железо поставишь. Сталкивался с проблемами не поддержки некоторых процессоров и видеокарт.

Comment: у меня лично стоит виртуалка на vmware с xCode и эмулятор даже айфона в ней запускается. Но я в учебных целях без публикации вот и спрашиваю.

Comment: @pavel, какая версия MAC оси? 10.11.5?

Comment: не помню, завтра буду за своим компом посмотрю. Вроде бы 10.11.3 или .4

Comment: @Alexis 10.11.4

Answer (score 0):

День добрый!
Что бы собирать приложения для iOS в любом случае нужна OS X.
Есть несколько вариантов как ее получить.

- Самый простой и самый дорогой - купить любой мак. Самое дешевое решение это мак мини. Но сразу скажу, на самых дешевых моделях не очень комфортно делать приложения - xcode притормаживает местами.
- Поставить хакентош. Сейчас ставится практически на любое железо. При адекватной конфигурации ПК будет летать. Хотя юридически это не легально, но не более ни легально чем пиратская винда. Все инструменты установятся и будут работать 100% даже на последней версии os x.
- os X в виртуалке (wmvare или virtualBox). имеет право, на жизнь, но как по мне выбор мазохистов. Работает туповато, все тормозит и жутко не удобно. Хакентош намного лучше.
- Веб сервер с os x. Честно не пробовал, ничего казать не могу. Наверное не плохой вариант.

Как вывод. Я бы рекомендовал мощный мак мини или хакентош если с деньгами проблемы.